# How to add Combobox as ContextMenu Item for Label Control. WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, contextmenu

I want to add combobox as ContextMenu item for some label control in wpf application in my code behind. How can I do it? I searched a lot over web but nothing comes productive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, we can do this is folowing way:

```
        ContextMenu contextmenu = new ContextMenu();
        ComboBox CmbColorMenu = new ComboBox();
        CmbColorMenu.ItemsSource = FontColors;// FontColors is list<objects>
        CmbColorMenu.DisplayMemberPath = "Text";
        contextmenu.Items.Add(CmbColorMenu);
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code is just a proof of concept on how you could build your `ContextMenu`. It will give you a `ComboBox` as the content of a `MenuItem`.

```
<Label Content="label with context menu">
    <Label.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="menu 1">
                <ComboBox>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="combo 1" IsSelected="True" />
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="combo 2" />
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="combo 3" />
                </ComboBox>
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Label.ContextMenu>
</Label>
```

Comment: Thanks Eirik..I want similar solution but using code behind.. How I can I do it in code behind?

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative...this allows the ComboBox to appear directly when you do the Right-Click. Copy and paste this into KAXAML to see it working.

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Grid>  
  <Label Content="Some Label">
  <Label.ContextMenu>
  <ContextMenu>
  <ContextMenu.Template>
  <ControlTemplate>
  <ComboBox SelectedIndex="0">
  <ComboBoxItem>One</ComboBoxItem>
  <ComboBoxItem>Two</ComboBoxItem>
  <ComboBoxItem>Three</ComboBoxItem>
  </ComboBox>
  </ControlTemplate>
  </ContextMenu.Template>
  </ContextMenu>
  </Label.ContextMenu>
  </Label>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

[image]

Comment: How can I do it in Code behind?